# Argument "No" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I need to assign values in the variable "TRTCD1" in two different classes as 1 and 2, based on the condition as stated in the R programming code below.

```
z$Treatment1.class<-with(z, ifelse(TRTCD1 == 0 & TRTCD1 == 40, 1,
    ifelse(TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50, 2)))
```

On running these code, I am getting the error:

> Argument "No" is missing, with no default

Here, `Treatment1.class` is a new variable in table `z` which holds the output of the class.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `ifelse()` needs three parameters: test, truth value, false value. Your inner `ifelse()` only has two parameters. You must specify a value when the test is false. It's unclear what you were trying to do with your code. You should describe your intent with words.

Comment: Basically i want to classify the values in TRTCD1 variable based on the following condition. If TRTCD1 is equal to 0 and 40 it should be grouped as 1. TRTCD1 greater than equal to 10 and less than equal to 30 and equal to 50 to be grouped as 2. I tried specifying the false value as 3, but it didn't produce the correct output. All the values were grouped as false (i.e. 3).  Let me know if there is a way to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can test possible solutions. That *should* work so there bust be something wrong with your data.

Comment: Please find the sample input data below.  TRTCD1<- c(
0
0
0
0
10
10
0
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
10
10
10
0
0
0
10
10
10
0
0
0
10
0
0
0
10
10
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
20
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
10
0
0
0
0
0
10
10
0
30
0
10
0
50)

Comment: Edit your original question with the data since it's difficult to properly format in the comments. If possible, use a `dput()` like described in the link I provided.

Comment: How `TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50` could be true?

Comment: data$dput<-with(z, ifelse(TRTCD1 == 0 & TRTCD1 == 40, 1,
    ifelse(TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50, 2,3)))

Comment: Basically the data in TRTCD1 represents the different treatments in forest plot. 10,20, 30 and 50 have treatment in them. Inorder to group them as treated plots i used TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50. On other hand 0 and 40 has no treatment effect, so i thought of grouping it as 2. Values which do not fall in these two cases are considered as false.

Comment: So you need `TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 | TRTCD1 == 50`.

Comment: I forgot to mention OR operator. Now i am able to get the correct output. Thank you Guys.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is as following.

```
ifelse(TRTCD1 == 0 & TRTCD1 == 40,
       1,
       ifelse(TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50, 2, *value if NO*)
)
```

Only the case where the second ifelse is TRUE is given.

Comment: I am getting the false value (i.e. if no) even if the condition is true.

Comment: Looks like you already solved it with @Pascal's advice: your condition was unsatisfiable, it needed to be `TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 | TRTCD1 == 50`

Answer (score 0):

This Error tells that else statement is missing which should be written as:

```
z$Treatment1.class<-with(z, ifelse(TRTCD1 == 0 & TRTCD1 == 40, 1,
    ifelse(TRTCD1 >= 10 & TRTCD1 <= 30 & TRTCD1 == 50, 2,<else code here>)))
```